# how to close fragment a when on fragment b?

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, google-signin

I am integrating sign in with google in fragment my android app. but when I sign in it open a new fragment b .but in when fragment b when I press on the place sign-in button was in the fragment it again shows the sign-in window

I already used         fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

login fragment (fragment a)

```
public class LoginFragment1 extends Fragment {
 int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
SignInButton signInButton;
LoginButton loginButton;
LinearLayout linearLayout,linearLayout1;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
private static final String EMAIL = "email";

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleSignInAccount account = 
    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
  if(account!=null){
updateUI(account);

     }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new 
     FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: "+loginResult );
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCancel: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: ",error );
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
     GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_fragment1, 
    container, false);
    //seting apps name
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    String text = "Lets<font color='#faa71a'>Go</font>";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text,  Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY), 
    TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    } else {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), 
    TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }



    //google login
     linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    signInButton = view.findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signInButton.performClick();
            signIn();
        }
    });
     mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getActivity(), gso);
    //facebook login
    linearLayout1 = view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
    loginButton = view.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    linearLayout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            loginButton.performClick();

        }
    });

    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile", "user_friends"));


    return view;
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        updateUI(null);
    }

}
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

private void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"signedin" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Fragment fragment = new StepFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
  account.getDisplayName()+"\n"+account.getEmail(),
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

}
```

user fragment (fragment b)

```
 public class StepFragment extends Fragment {
Button Logoutl;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step, container, false);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
 GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = (GoogleSignInClient) GoogleSignIn.getClient(getActivity(), gso);
    Logoutl = view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Logoutl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
        }
    });
    Fragment fragment = new LoginFragment1();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: You can try fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment) remove the current fragment. Not the last one

Answer (score 0):

Inside Login Fragment create TAG name for Login Fragment like this `public static String TAG = "Login";`

> Create a function inside Second Fragment like below

```
public void removeFragmentByTag(String tag) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

When you are in Second Fragment, Call this method by passing Login fragment TAG name like

```
removeFragmentByTag(Login.TAG);
```

And it will remove login fragment

Answer (score 0):

alternative approach is using a library such as Otto to send an event on the event bus. Due to the inherent nature of fragments, all fragments lying on top of each other added using the add method are active and not paused.... Thus any event that you fire will pass all the active listeners.

Make an event class

```
public class CloseFrag{}
```

Declare your event bus in the fragments where you need it

```
private static final Bus eventBus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
```

Register the event bus in the onResume of the fragments where you need it:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    eventBus.register(this);

    super.onResume();
}
```

Unregister the event bus in the onPause of the fragments where you need it

```
@Override
public void onPause() {

    eventBus.unregister(this);

    super.onPause();
}
```

In fragment where google sign in is present, once sign in is done fire the event

```
eventBus.post(new CloseFrag());
```

In the fragment that you want to close, listen to the events after registering the bus

```
@Subscribe
public void event(CloseFrag event){

   //Take necessary action eg popBackStack() or getActivity().finish() as per your need

}
```